# How to control the size of faces in geometry nodes

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, mathematics

So, I want to create a structure only with geometry nodes. My structure so far resembles an ico sphere with hole in it. I figured what I needed to do first add volume to the mesh,figure out a way to delete one face from the mesh, and inset it. My question is how do I control the size of the delete geometry?

Also, I am completely new to this, I figured the best way to learn is to make a project for myself so it is completely and mostly possible I am going about this wrong and I am open to any and all suggestions.

[image: my node setup so far]

[image: What I am trying to recreate]

Comment: so are you basically asking how to expand a selection? (also please specify what version you are using; different versions often have difficulty solution as geometry nodes progresses)

Comment: you can e.g. use scale elements node. Pls provide at least the node tree you use for your hole so that we can help you. Even better would be to provide a minimized blend file with your problem. why? because you want free help from us in our spare time. So you should make it as easy as possible to help you quickly. thx.

Comment: It is not clear to me what are you asking for? To scale Face see my Answer, but you described your Q How to control size of deleted geometry ... How can be controled something that is already deleted (doesnt exist)? Please add some mockup or sketch of desired result to give us a better picture of what you are looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How to control size of face in GN ...

[image]
[image]